# Python unittests, statement before test cases

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Imagine I have tests like that:

```
import unittest

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

  print("Starting")

  def test_first(self):
    .....
```

Is the `print` statement guaranteed to be executed before `test_first()` and the rest? From what I've seen it does get executed first, but are there any edge cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `setUp()`([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)) and `setUpClass()`([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass)) methods for this. The `setUp()` method is executed before each individual test while the `setUpClass()` method is executed before all the tests in this class run.

```
import unittest

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("Starting all the tests.")

    def setUp(self):
        print("Starting another test.")

    def test_first(self):
        ...
```